# Estimating missing values in time-series data frame based on a "rate of change"

Tags: r, loops, time-series, na

I am trying to use a loop in R to estimate values that will replace the NAs in my data frame based on a rate of change ("rate") that multiplies my last value (ok, this is confusing, but please refer to the example below). This is something similar to my data:

```
l1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,27,31,0.5)
l2 <- c(NA,8,12,28,39,0.5)
l3 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,39,0.3)
l4 <- c(NA,NA,11,15,31,0.2)
l5 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,51,0.9)

data <- as.data.frame(rbind(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5))
colnames(data) <- c("dbh1","dbh2","dbh3","dbh4","dbh5","rate")
```

So I created a loop to identify my first no-NA value in each line, then use that value to estimate its previous values based on the "rate". So for instance, in row 1, the first NA value would be replace by **"27-(0.5*3)"**, then the second one would be **"27-(0.5*2)"** and the third one by **"27-(0.5*1)"**. This is the loop I came up with. I know the first part (the outside loop) works but the the inside one doesn't:

```
for (i in 1: nrow(data)) {
  dbh.cols <- data3[i,c("dbh1","dbh2","dbh3","dbh4","dbh5")]

  sample.year <- which(dbh.cols != "NA")

  data$first.dbh[i] <- min(dbh.cols, na.rm = T)
  data$first.index[i] <- min(sample.year)

  for (j on 1: (min(sample.year)-1)) {
    ifelse(is.na(data[i,j]), min(dbh.cols, na.rm = T) - (min(sample.year)-j)*rate[i,j], data[i,j])
  }
}
```

I am not good at programming so probably my internal loop strategy with "ifelse" is too weird (and wrong) but I just couldn't think of anything else that would work here... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** This uses no explicit loops, just an `apply`.  It assumes that the NAs are all leading as in the example given.

```
fillIn <- function(x) {
   rate <- tail(x, 1)
   n <- sum(is.na(x)) # no of NAs
   c(x[n+1] - rate * seq(n, 1), na.omit(x))
}
replace(data, TRUE, t(apply(data, 1, fillIn)))
```

giving:

```
   dbh1 dbh2 dbh3 dbh4 dbh5 rate
l1 25.5 26.0 26.5 27.0   31  0.5
l2  7.5  8.0 12.0 28.0   39  0.5
l3 37.8 38.1 38.4 38.7   39  0.3
l4 10.6 10.8 11.0 15.0   31  0.2
l5 47.4 48.3 49.2 50.1   51  0.9
```

**2)** Here is a second approach that uses `na.approx` from the zoo package. It does not require `apply`.  Here `data1` has the same content as `data` except that the first column is filled in.  The other NAs remain.  The last line uses `na.approx` to fill in the remaining NAs linearly.

```
library(zoo)

NAs <- rowSums(is.na(data))
data1 <- cbind( data[cbind(1:nrow(data), NAs + 1)] - data$rate * NAs, data[-1] )
replace(data, TRUE, t(na.approx(t(data1))))
```

giving:

```
   dbh1 dbh2 dbh3 dbh4 dbh5 rate
l1 25.5 26.0 26.5 27.0   31  0.5
l2  7.5  8.0 12.0 28.0   39  0.5
l3 37.8 38.1 38.4 38.7   39  0.3
l4 10.6 10.8 11.0 15.0   31  0.2
l5 47.4 48.3 49.2 50.1   51  0.9
```

**2a)** A variation on (2) uses `na.locf` in the middle line to bring forward the first non-NA in each row.  The first and last lines are the same.

```
library(zoo)

NAs <- rowSums(is.na(data))
data1 <- cbind(na.locf(t(data), fromLast = TRUE)[1, ] - data$rate * NAs, data[-1])
replace(data, TRUE, t(na.approx(t(data1))))
```

Comment: Much more concise. I like this one!

Comment: Thanks, G. Grothendieck! Omg, you would be able to turn my 100-code lines into 10 probably... hehe

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use multiple for loops for this. Here is some simplified code to do what you want just for the `for` loop. Working explicitly with your `data` we need to get the first non-NA value from each row.

```
for_estimate <- apply(data, 1, function(x) x[min(which(is.na(x) == FALSE))])
```

Secondly, we need to determine what integer to multiply the rate by for each row depending on how many NA values there are.

```
# total number of NA values per row
n_na <- apply(data,1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) )

# make it a matrix with a 0's appended on
n_na <- matrix(c(n_na, rep(0, nrow(data) * (ncol(data)-1))), 
           nrow = nrow(data), ncol = ncol(data)-1)

# fill in the rest of the matrix
for(i in 2:ncol(n_na)){
  n_na[,i] <- n_na[,i-1] -1
}
```

Once we have that we can use this code to back fill the NA values in that way you are interested in.

```
for(i in (ncol(data)-1):1){
  if(sum(is.na(data[,i]))>0){
  to_fill <- which(is.na(data[,i])==TRUE)

  data[to_fill,i] <- for_estimate[to_fill] - (data$rate[to_fill]*(n_na[to_fill,i])
  }

}
```

output

```
   dbh1 dbh2 dbh3 dbh4 dbh5 rate
l1 25.5 26.0 26.5 27.0   31  0.5
l2  7.5  8.0 12.0 28.0   39  0.5
l3 37.8 38.1 38.4 38.7   39  0.3
l4 10.6 10.8 11.0 15.0   31  0.2
l5 47.4 48.3 49.2 50.1   51  0.9
```